# x:Bind in WinUI3 Binding to a datetime

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

I am trying to bind current DateTime to a textblock object in WinUI3.

```
<Page
    x:Class="HabitTracker.Screens.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HabitTracker.Screens"
    xmlns:sys="using:System"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid> 
      <Grid>
        <GridView MaxHeight="500" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Habits}">
          <GridView.HeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="45">
             <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:DateTime.Now}" />
             <TextBlock Text="hello2" />
             <TextBlock Text="hello2" />
             <TextBlock Text="hello2" />
            <TextBlock Text="hello2" />
         </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.HeaderTemplate>
```

...
But my binding doesn't work. I get empty string on the UI while running the application.

I have the following namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:sys="using:System"
```

What am I missing?

Note: I also read this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings although it is for UWP, not WinUi3 documentation.

I am using WindowsAppSDK 1.1.1

Comment: Works fine for me (using WindowsAppSDK 1.1.1). But you can use a Converter too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.

Comment: weird. i use the same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your behavior when putting the Textblock into a `DataTemplate` of a `ListView.HeaderTemplate`. I'm not sure about the reason but I suspect the behavior is related to the **DataContext**. When you put the `TextBlock` into a `DataTemplate`, the `DataContext` will be changed into the root control of the GridView template.

A workaround that I used is to put the `TextBlock` into a **UserControl** instead of directly putting the `TextBlock`into the `DataTemplate`.

UserControl:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:DateTime.Now}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Page:

```
 <ListView x:Name="MyListView" Width="500" Height="500" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:UserControl1 />
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <x:String >123</x:String>
        <x:String >123</x:String>
        <x:String >123</x:String>
        <x:String >123</x:String>
    </ListView>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Workaround works ineed. Thanks